# How to disable automatic syncing of a Store in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

ExtJS version is `ext-4.0.7-gpl`.

When syncing a Store, the server returns me the same object in JSON format, but populated with generated Ids, that I need to put into my store data. The identifiers are in enclosed entities, like this:

```
{
    "id": 46,
    "name": "Excel",
    "typeExt": [{
        "ext": "xls",
        "id": "137",
        "isMain": "false",
    }, {
        "ext": "xslx",
        "id": "136",
        "isMain": "false",
    }]
}
```

So the ids `137` and `136` are generated on server-side.

I am trying to make it in a store's proxy **(edit: Ajax type)** (which itself could be wrong):

```
proxy.afterRequest = function(request) {
     if (request.action === 'create' && request.records.length == 1) {
         me.store.autoSync = false;
         var created = Ext.JSON.decode(request.operation.response.responseText);
         request.records[0].set('id', created.id);
         request.records[0].set('typeExt', created.typeExt);
         //request.records[0].modified = {};
         //request.records[0].dirty = false;
         me.store.autoSync = true;
     }
     if (request.action === 'update' && request.records.length == 1) {
         var updated = Ext.JSON.decode(request.operation.response.responseText);
         me.store.autoSync = false;
         request.records[0].set('typeExt', updated.typeExt);
         me.store.autoSync = true;
     }

 };
```

See the commented variants.

If I don't set `autoSync` to `false`, it gets looped infinitely.

If I don't clear those `read-only` fields `modified` and `dirty`, the modified records are included in the next syncronization request, if I edited another record, it sends an *Array* of records which breaks my server-side service.

If I clear `dirty` and `modified` like it is shown in the commented lines, the update operation works only once. I press Update button in RowEditing plugin dialog, but it never sends the needed request to the server for the second time.

In the latter case I guess I broke something by hand-editing the readonly fields, but I can not find what.

How do people usually handle issues liek this?

> PS.

```
request.records[0].commit(true); || request.records[0].editing = false; 

|| request.records[0].beginEdit();
```

Were tried with no seccess too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this working for grids stores with Ext 4.0.7, but having similar issues with tree stores. All this with a direct proxy (and autosync true)

If you look at the code of Ext.data.Store::onCreateRecords, you'll see that the store records are replaced by those returned from the server, given the order is the same.

So, it is pretty straight-forward: just return from the server the same json/object sent to the create method, but with the id set and it should update them automatically on the store.

I know this is of not much help, but perhaps will give you some direction.

I think it would help if you mention:

- the type of proxy you're using
- the exact ext version
- perhaps the code initiating the creation of the record

Comment: thanks! the code is quite messy. it's a `Picker`, which opens a grid to edit `typeExt` subarray. there are two methods, `valueToRaw` and `rawToValue`  that make String from a `typeExt` array, made by concatenation of `ext` fields. actually, with `Picker` it works, but they want me to allow to hand edit the concatenated String and make a generic `typeExt` array from it. i debugged that code to be sure that the `pickerfield` becomes updated accordingly... if i find how to temporarily disable autoSync, and the problem stays, i'll look closer into that code, maybe after syncing this system fails.

Comment: thanks again, though your answer is not exactly for my question, you helped me to resolve my issue. i'd like to accept your answer but it's not by the rules of the site i guess. you may modify your answer with 'there is no good way to disable autosync' and i'll accept it, ok?

Answer (score 3):

While this won't do you much good on Ext 4.0.7, the [suspendAutoSync](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-suspendAutoSync) and [resumeAutoSync](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-resumeAutoSync) methods were added in Ext 4.1.0.  Hopefully this will be useful to someone else.